# How to get azure cdn link for file in azure blob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I have Azure Blob and added for it Azure CDN.

How to get link to cdn for uploaded to blob file?

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(configuration.ConnectionString);
var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference("container");

CloudBlobContainer container = await _containerFactory.CreateAsync("files", cancellationToken);
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("file-name.png");

await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream, cancellationToken);

return blockBlob.Uri; // return blob blob url
```

`blockBlob.Uri` returns blob url, but I need CDN uri?

Is it possible to get CDN uri based on c# code? Without replacing part of uri to cdn endpoint.

Comment: You are uploading the file to a blob storage account, but you are not adding that link to the CDN, so why do you expect to receive a CDN link?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto can you please explain how to do it? Please provide description step by step or some post with explanation

Comment: So you upload a file to blob storage and you want to send back the CDN url to the user ? can you not just put the CDN name into a config variable ???

Comment: @AntonZimm https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-app-dev-net

Comment: @Thomas it required to parse file uri and replace to CDN url? I don't like this solution, I try to get already correct link in response.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto this topic about CDM managements, not about Blob and CDN work together. It is not my case

Comment: @AntonZimm, sorry trying to understand your use case... maybe there are other solution you need to think about

Comment: Did author managed to solve it? Get cdn endpoint for a bolb?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm facing the same issue. I don't know how to make blob service to return CDN endpoint URL associated to the blob.

Answer (score 0):

better available solution -- concatenate strings with URL of CDN and file name